# akka cluster singleton proxy can not identify actor on none leader node

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I was trying to build a two-node akka cluster,and both of the nodes are configured as seed node. At each node I create actor and locate it by these ways below:

```
    akka {
  //loglevel = "DEBUG"
  log-config-on-start = on
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0
    }
  }
  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551",
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"
    ]
    roles = [
      "transport"
    ]
    auto-down = on
  }
}
final String SINGLETON_GROUP = "client";
getContext().system().actorOf(
                            ClusterSingletonManager.defaultProps(
                                    Props.create(ClientActor.class, channelActive.getCtx()),
                                    loginMessage.getId(),
                                    PoisonPill.getInstance(),
                                    "transport"
                            ), SINGLETON_GROUP
                    );
private ActorRef getActor(String id) {
    ActorRef remoteActor = getContext().system().actorOf(
            ClusterSingletonProxy.defaultProps("user/" + SINGLETON_GROUP + "/" + id,
                    "transport"));
    return remoteActor;
}
```

what I expected is that I can create an actor at any node, and locate it everywhere as long as I got its singletonPath.
  However, the result is : the getActor() only works at "leader" node, and can not identify at other nodes.
  If I got wrong understanding about clusterSingleton ?

Comment: Can you please verify that you're using `provider = akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider` or just paste your `application.connf`

Comment: hi, I post the application.conf, I was using the ClusterActorRefProvider